# FontAwesome with React and server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, server-side-rendering

I'm experiencing an issue with `dom.watch()` function of FortAwesome (https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/tree/fc05448cae99f44fe80bfc186a3a7552c57c31b3#processing-i-tags-into-svg-using-font-awesome)

My website is rendered by server side rendering, in the case of the menu of the website is server side rendered, icons doesn't appears and `<i>` tags are not replaced by `dom.watch()` function.

When I render the page on client, icons (`<i>`) are replaced by `svg` and icons appears.

My menu use https://github.com/alpertuna/react-metismenu and I can't use `<FortAwesomeIcon>` to put icon on item menu.

Thanks you in advance for your help